# Ввод числового значения через сообщение telebot. Python

Tags: python, telebot

Как при использовании telebot получить из сообщения числовое значение? При использовании **i = message.text.lower()** пользователь вводит число, но получается строчное значение, которое впоследствии нельзя использовать для дальнейшего математического вычисления. Есть ли методы, для перевода строчного значения введенного из сообщения в числовое?

Comment: `i = int(message.text.lower())`

Comment: Смотря какое число ожидается, целое или с точкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте преобразование в `int()`:

```
i = int(message.text.lower())
```

И рекомендую вам [почитать](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/04_data_structures/index.html) про типы данных в Python.